# How do you sign extend 2-digit hexadecimal to 4-digit hexadecimal?

Tags: hex, bit, extend, sign

How would 0x99 be represented as 4-digit hexadecimal using sign extension?

Comment: How do you think it would be? What’s the sign bit here and how do you extend it? Have a go at it

Comment: I think it would just be 0x9999.

Comment: What would be your logic for that? Also think what 0x99 signed is in decimal and what 0x9999 signed is in decimal. Would they be the same?

Comment: Actually, since it's a negative hexadecimal. It be 0xFF99 right?

Comment: Yes, it would be 0xff99 since all the added bits will be the same as the sign bit, hence the name “sign extending”

Comment: Since in binary 0x99 would be 10011001. Extend 8 more bits would be 1111 1111 1001 1001 = 0xFF99.

Answer (score 0):

example 1: we have A2h 8-bit number. We first change the character to number.A(10),B(11),C(12),D(13),E(14),F(15). So our hex number actually is (10)2h so it starts with 1 which means there is 1 at the most left bit.So the rest will be FF. The answer is FFA2h 16-bit number.

example2: We have 08h 8bit number. The most left bit is 0. So rest will be 0. The answer is 0008h.